# Crawlers/SEO Friendly/Mod Rewrite/It doesn't make any sense

Tags: mod-rewrite, robots.txt

So I am attached to this rather annoying project where a clients client is all nit picky about the little things and he's giving my guy hell who is gladly returning the favor by following the good old rule of shoving shi* down the chain of command.

Now my question. The application consists basically of 3 different mini projects. The backend interface for the administrator, backend interface for the client and the frontend for everyone.

I was specifically asked to apply MOD_REWRITE rules to make things SEO friendly. That was the ultimate aim, so this was basically an exercise in making things more search friendly rather than making the links aesthetically better looking.

So I worked on the frontend, which is basically the landing page for everyone. It looks beautiful, the links are at worst followed by one backslash.

My clients issue. He wants to know why the backend interfaces for the admin and user are still displaying those gigantic ugly links. And these are very very ugly links, I am talking three to four backslashes followed by various get sequences and what not, so you can probably understand the complexities behind MOD_REWRITING something such as this.

In the spur of the moment I said that I left it the way it was to make sure the backend interface wouldn't be sniffed up by any crawlers. 
But I am not sure if that's necessarily true. Where do crawlers stop? When do they give up on trying to parse links? I know I can use a .robot file to specify rules. But, as indigenous creatures, what are their instincts?

I know this is more of a rant than anything and I am running a very high risk of having my first question rejected :| But hey, it feels good to have this off my chest.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do crawlers stop? When do they give up on trying to parse links?

Robots.txt does not work for all bots.

You can use basic authentication or limited access by IP to hide back-end, if no files are needed for front-end.

If not practicable, try to send 404 or 401 headers for back-end files. But this is just an idea, no guarantee.

> But, as indigenous creatures, what are their instincts?

Hyperlinks, toolbars and browser-sided, pre-activated functions for malware-, spam- and fraud-warnings...